# Objective C: How to switch from one Tab bar to another via program

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have 5 different tabs in my tabbar controller.

My intention is to be able to switch from one tab bar via code. For example I am currently in the 5th tab of the app and when I click on the 'done' button, the app should switch my view to the rootview controller belonging to the 1st tab.

Any advise on how I can do this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Set `selectedViewController` property of `UITabBarController`:

```
self.myTabBarController.selectedViewController = myViewController;
```

Use as below

```
self.myTabBarController.selectedViewController 
    = [self.myTabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: How can I restart the same tab from TabBarController ?

Answer (score 10):

Heres a simpler answer (if you know the index of the Tab Bar item is not in the "more" view controllers):
just get a reference of the tabController and set the "selectedIndex" property

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_6