# Change Selected TabBarItem via code?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

I was wonder how you would go about changing the selected tab of a UITabBar via code?

and yes I know this thread is a copy of:
[Objective C: How to switch from one Tab bar to another via program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382139/objective-c-how-to-switch-from-one-tab-bar-to-another-via-program)
but that solution didn't work.

Thanks!

-Shredder2794

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for your case?

```
[tabBar setSelectedItem:[[tabBar items] objectAtIndex:index]];
```

or

```
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:index];
```

Comment: Although the code doesn't throw any warnings or errors is simply doesn't change the tab. Then I ran the following line of code and the console returned NULL. `NSLog(@"%@",[[mainTabBar.mainTabBar items]objectAtIndex:0]);`

Comment: Why `mainTabBar.mainTabBar`? What's the type of your `mainTabBar` object and how did you created it?

Comment: mainTabBar is the name of a UITabBarController class and mainTabBar is the name for a UITabBar that's in that class. I'm calling this from a different class instead of mainTabBar because the compiler kept throwing an exception saying that setting the tab bars

Comment: So you have a `UITabBarController`... I didn't know that because you just mentioned `UITabBar` in your question. Try `[mainTabBar setSelectedIndex:0]` to see whether this works?

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try that in the morning but now I'm going to bed ;)

Comment: And I think `mainTabBar.tabBar` is the correct property for the pointer to the UITabBar object. Did you declare `mainTabBar.mainTabBar` yourself?

Comment: [mainTabBar setSelectedIndex:0] worked perfectly! Thanks for all your help Halley!

Comment: My pleasure. I've revised my answer accordingly. If it did work please vote and/or accept it, thanks!